# Clone a form and increment ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, clone

I am fairly new to coding and this is the first website I have built so I apologize if this is simple or my code looks poor. I've looked through answers to this problem and have copied some of the solutions to try to make them work for my form. I am attempting to make the form cloned as a whole and the cloned object then becomes Wire 2...3..etc using JavaScript and or JQuery. Any help is appreciated.

Here is the form and a solution that I have found:

```js
  var regex = /^(.+?)(\d+)$/i;
var cloneIndex = $(".clonedInput").length;

function clone(){
    $(this).parents(".clonedInput").clone()
        .appendTo("body")
        .attr("id", "clonedInput" +  cloneIndex)
        .find("*")
        .each(function() {
            var id = this.id || "";
            var match = id.match(regex) || [];
            if (match.length == 3) {
                this.id = match[1] + (cloneIndex);
            }
        })
        .on('click', 'button.clone', clone)
        .on('click', 'button.remove', remove);
    cloneIndex++;
}
function remove(){
    $(this).parents(".clonedInput").remove();
}
$("button.clone").on("click", clone);

$("button.remove").on("click", remove);
    </script>
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<div id="clonedInput1" class="clonedInput">
<center><h1>New WIRE</h1></center>
   
<center><div id="wiregauge" name="wiregauge"> Size of Wire<select name="dropdown" value="">
   <option value="18" var message ="18g">18 gauge</option>
   <option value="16" var message ="16g">16 gauge</option>
   <option value="14" var message ="14g">14 gauge</option>
   <option value="12" var message ="12g" >12 gauge</option>
   <option value="10" var message ="10g">10 gauge</option>
    </select></div></center>
    
  <center><p id="lengthconv">25.4 millimeters equals 1 inch</p></center>
       <div id="wirelength" name="wirelength">
<center><div id="wirel">Length of Wire (in MM)<input type="number" min="152.4" max="2540" id="wireli" name="wireli">
<label for="wirel"></label></div></center>
</div>

    

<center><div id="wirenlid"><label for="wirenlid">Text on LEFT side of the Wire</label><input type="text" name="wirenlid" id="wiretextlinput" value=" ">
</div></center>

    
<center>
 Text reads UP <input type="radio" name="left1" id="lup" value="UP"><br>
 Text reads DOWN <input type="radio" name="left1" id="ldwn"value="DOWN">
</center>
    
<center><div id="wireterml1" >Termination on Left Side<select name="wirelt" id="wiretl"> 
    <option name="fork" value="FORK">Fork</option>
    <option name="ring" value="RING">Ring</option>
    <option name="male disconnect" value="MDIS">Male Disconnect</option>
    <option name="female disconnect" value="FMDIS">Female Disconnect</option>
    </select></div></center>
    
    <center><div id="wirenrid">Text on RIGHT side of the Wire<input type="text" id="wiretextrinput" value=" " name="wirenrid"></div>
       </center>
<center>
   Text reads UP<input type="radio" name="right1" id="rup" value="UP"><br>
 Text reads DOWN <input type="radio" name="right1" id="rdwn" value="DOWN">
</center>
    
    <center><div id="wiretermr1">Termination on Right Side<select name="wirert" id="wirert">
    <option name="fork" value="FORK">Fork</option>
    <option name="ring" value="RING">Ring</option>
    <option name="male disconnect" value="MDIS">Male Disconnect</option>
    <option name="female disconnect" value="FMDIS">Female Disconnect</option>
    </select> </div></center>
    
<center><div id="wirecolor" >Color of Wire<select name="wirencolor" id="wirecolor1">
    <option value="BLACK">Black</option>
  <option value="WHITE">White</option>
  <option value="GRN/YEL">Green/Yellow</option>
  <option value="RED">Red</option>
  <option value="BLUE">Blue</option><option value="PURPLE">Purple</option> <option value="ORANGE">Orange</option><option value="BROWN">Brown</option><option value="YELLOW">Yellow</option><option value="WHT/BLU">White/BLue</option><option value="WHT/ORG">White/ Orange</option><option value="WHT/LTBLU">White/Light Blue</option><option 
  value="GRAY">Gray</option><option value="LTBLU">Light Blue</option>
    </select></div></center>
<!--Types of options needed include: Wire gauge, length, color, printing, and termination... Ring/fork/male disconnect/ female disconnect 18 16 14 12 10 gauge -->
<div class="actions">
   <button class="clone">Clone</button> 
</div>
    </div>
</body>   </html>
```

Here is the Jsfiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/CJShult/r44nosx7/

Comment: What's the specific problem you're having?

Comment: Why not just use the built-in `cloneNode()` DOM method? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode instead of writing your own?

Comment: I didn't Know about the CloneNode() DOM method, again sorry I'm really new to this and have next to no experience. Thank you @Scott Marcus the link you provided helps a lot.